# print specific word(number) out of a line

Tags: python

I can use Python to print one line in the .txt ,say, "[aln-core]:10000000 sequences have been processed"

But I want to print the number(10000000, this is the information I want); how can I do that/
thx

Comment: Are all your lines of that pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get the 10000000 out of some line="[aln-core]:10000000 sequences have been processed"?

If you're sure that line's always going look like that, try

```
line.split(':')[1].split[0]
```

I mean ...

```
line = "[aln-core]:10000000 sequences have been processed"

line.split(':')[1]
'10000000 sequences have been processed'

line.split(':')[1].split()[0]
'10000000'
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
line = '[aln-core]:10000000 sequences have been processed'
line = ''.join(c for c in line if c.isdigit())
```

A regex solution:

```
import re
line = '[aln-core]:10000000 sequences have been processed'
print re.search('\d+', line).group()
```